# How to compile using Free Pascal

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, freepascal

Guys I got a source from a friend that is suppose to help me learn RE a lot but I got error

> Error:identifier not found "TResourceStream"
>   "Bool"
>   "TMemoryStream"
>   "TResourceInfo"
>   "try"

And

> Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but " identifier MS" found

Please help I need to compile this.
Excuse me please I know nothing yet, about programming.

Here is the source

function EnumResourceNames(hModule: HMODULE; // EXE handle returned from LoadLibrary/Ex
      lpType: PChar; // resource type (eg: RT_RCDATA)
      lpEnumFunc: ENUMRESNAMEPROC; // callback      function address
      lParam: Integer // long integer (eg: pointer to an object)
    ): BOOL; stdcall;

```
function CB_EnumDfmNameProc(hModule: THandle; lpszType, lpszName: PChar;
  lParam: Integer): Boolean; stdcall;
var
  ms: TMemoryStream;
  rs: TResourceStream;
  Buffer: array of Byte;
begin
  with TResourceInfo(lParam) do
  begin
    rs := TResourceStream.Create(TResourceInfo(lParam).Module,
    lpszname, lpszType); // load resource in memory
    try
      ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        try
          SetLength(Buffer, 4);
          rs.Read(Buffer[0],          SizeOf(Buffer)); // read the first 4 bytes
          if string(Buffer) = 'TPF0' then // is it a DFM resource?
          begin
            rs.Seek(0, 0);
            ObjectBinaryToText(rs, ms); // decode DFM
            ms.Seek(0, 0);
            AddDfm(StrPas(lpszName), ms); // add it to our own list
          end;
        except
          raise;
        end;
      finally
        ms.Free;
      end;
    finally
      rs.free;
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;

procedure TResourceInfo.EnumDfmNames;
begin
  if FModule > 0 then // if an EXE file has been loaded
    EnumResourceNames(FModule, RT_RCDATA, // go and search RCDATA resources
      @CB_EnumDfmNameProc, Integer(Self));
end;
```

Comment: to format the code, copy it to your text editor, select all and type the TAB key twice if tab size is set to 2 or once if tab size is set to 4. Then copy from the editor and paste to S.O

Comment: Still there is an error